# R - filter function ends up adding a patient?

Tags: r, dataframe, debugging, dplyr

I have a large dataset of different patient interactions with a university hospital (100,000s of rows and columns).

I have 2 main variables I am concerned about. One is the patient id variable (pid) and the second is a binary flag variable. Im writing code so that if any row (interaction) of a particular patient is flagged (1), that patient should be removed from the dataset.

```
hosp <- hosp %>%
    group_by(pid) %>%
    filter(max(flag)==0) %>%
    ungroup()
```

The problem now is that when I check the number of *unique* patients with this code

```
n_distinct(hosp$pid, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I get the value 7834 when I run it before my filtering code, but 7835 when I run it right after!

Why an extra person?

The correct total number of rows get filtered out. Just the values of the pid variable are playing up.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is counting the number of distinct values across all columns. Perhaps you want `n_distinct(hosp$pid, na.rm=TRUE)` only distinct PID.

```
NROW(iris)
#[1] 150
n_distinct(iris)
#[1] 149
n_distinct(iris$Petal.Width)
#[1] 22
iris2<-iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(max(Petal.Width)==2.5) %>%
  ungroup() 
n_distinct(iris2)
#[1] 49
n_distinct(iris2$Petal.Width)
#[1] 12
```

Comment: Sorry I had meant to write hosp$pid. I have corrected this now.

Comment: @Spock366373 Lets find out what is different between the two results. Reload your original data, perform the filter and assign to a new variable name. Then compare `setdiff(iris, iris_filtered)` and `setdiff(iris_filtered, iris)`.